# gcloud app.yaml Python setting for resources

Tags: python, runtime, gcloud, app.yaml

How could we set resources for Python runtime inside app.yaml?
The below gives me an error when it reaches to resources section. however, If I chose nodejs14 as runtime it works

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 1
env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: 'production'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [2 flavors of App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments): standard; flex

Using standard there is no resource section in app.yaml because the resources are determined by the instance type.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref

Using flex, `resources` section is used to determine the (Compute Engine) VM type.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml#resource-settings

If you wish to use standard and specify resources, you'll need to specify the instance type:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard#instance_classes

If your wish to use flex, you can specify the CPU and memory using the `resources` section.

Comment: Could you please provide the .Yaml file how to set it with the cheapest option? My files are simple static and  I  still could not figure out

Comment: If you're only hosting static content, consider using Google Cloud Storage instead: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website Otherwise, since you have a new question, please consider posting a new question.

Comment: I tested that but because I do not have my own domain, I have problem with identifying the root of the contents. My static app is with React and it has some Route elements that because I could not identify the root, my components loading collapses